# DomDocument iterating through a few divs. Have a handle on the parent element

Tags: php, html, domdocument

Ok so I need to iterate through a few divs and extract the `<a></a>` tag in each div and the content inside the tags.

There is a div with an ID a few lines up in the document, it is the closest I can get to the divs I need, The real div which the `<a></a>` tags I want are in is the 6th child div within the element which has the ID. I have this so far:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$container = $doc->getElementById('container');
$containerDivs= $container->getElementsByTagName('div');

// Problem here, item() returns DOMNode which has no getElementsByTagName()
$sideBar = $containerDivs->item(5);

// This is what I want to do but can't because my $sideBar is a DOMNode not a
// DOMElement so it does not have a getElementsByTagName() method
$categories = $sideBar->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

How do I get my `$sideBar` to be a `DOMElement` so I have the functionality I need?

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DOMXPath` as an alternative:

```
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
$categories = $selector->query('//*[@id="container"]/div[5]/a');
```

Learn more about [`XPath`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) and [`DOMXPath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

Comment: Doesn't seem too bad. Can I do my getElementsByTagName() or something similar after that? Is DOMXPath similar to DOMDocument except it gives you more control over everything?

Comment: You have to pass the `DOMDocument` to the `DOMXPath` constructor.  `DOMXpath` then provides an interface to perform XPath queries on the `DOMDocument`. `$categories` will be a `DOMNodeList` as the result of `DOMDocument::getElementsById()`